# A glossary style which is not alphabetically sorted

Tags: glossaries

I am using `glossaries` package to print glossaries. Is it possible to have glossaries in order of their occurrences and not alphabetically?

MWE -

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{1}{name={7},description={abcd}}
\newglossaryentry{2}{name={4},description={pqrs}}
\newglossaryentry{3}{name={2},description={wxyz}}

\begin{document}
This is \gls{1}.\\
This is \gls{2}.\\
This is \gls{3}.\\
\printglossaries    
\end{document}
```

This will arrange the glossaries in alphabetical order and 2, 4, 7 will be the sequence of glossaries. I want them to be 7, 4, 2 as they are in the document. Is there any glossary style available for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various options for sorting the list using the `sort=<method>` package option, as described on page 75 of the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf). For sorting according to the order of the `\newglossaryentry` commands you can use `sort=def`. For sorting according to the order of the `\gls` commands in the main text you can use `sort=use`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[xindy,sort=def]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{1}{name={7},description={abcd}}
\newglossaryentry{2}{name={4},description={pqrs}}
\newglossaryentry{3}{name={2},description={wxyz}}

\begin{document}
This is \gls{1}.\\
This is \gls{2}.\\
This is \gls{3}.\\
\printglossaries    
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]